# Is there a way to write a Batch-file which will Return services into their Default mode?

Tags: windows, batch, script, batch-file, services

I had already twice a problem with my computer were it just went out of controll and most of the functions were incontrolable, including services like Sound, Brightness, Internet and some other. Later I found out that all this problems were because suddenly more then 70% of all my **SERVICES.MSC** were off. I don't know what caused that neither I know whats the proper way to fix that. But I've been told that I have to reinstall my Windows, but I though of looking up all the Services that has to be *Started* and *Stoped* and their *Startup Type* on an Identical laptop to then *Start* and set all the *Starup Types* the same. And guess what... It worked. But it took me HOURS.

Thats why I though when next time my **services** are going to freak out, it would really be helpful to have a *.bat* file with a piece of code that will set aall the **services.msc** to their default modes and order. Where I have to just click it to activate and it would do all the Hour job for me.

*Actualy it is not even neccessary to be writen in *batch*, in *C++* or *JavaScript* would do.

also if anybody know what could've been the cause of the *services.msc* to freak out, that would also be apreciated.

Comment: Black Viper has a list of Windows standard service configurations. http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/ I thought that they had scripts or registry files to set them up for you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what would cause the freak-out, sorry, but it's easy enough to restore the services to the states you want them in.

The first and easiest way to do this is to take a backup of the service registry keys. Under regedit, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` and then Export that key as a .REG file (use the File menu or right-click the key). Save the generated .REG file somewhere. *If you know what you're doing* you can edit this file (it's plain text) to remove services that you don't care about or that you have intentionally removed (for example, because you uninstalled some software). Once you have this file, you can restore all the registry settings in it (which means all the service configuration data) by double-clicking it (this merges the data in the file back into the registry). Taking or merging this backup will require Administrator permissions. Note that this won't actually re-start the services; you will need to do that manually, or to reboot the computer.

If you want to fully script the repair process, you can write a .CMD file that calls the `sc` program (Service Control Manager command-line utility). It's pretty well documented; you can, for example, learn what commands it supports by just running `sc` and see the details of a command, such as "config", by running `sc config`. For example, you can change the startup type of the Server service (which is actually called by the legacy name "LanmanServer"; "Server" is just a "display name") to Automatic (which is its default value) and then start it thus:

```
sc config LanmanServer start= auto
sc start LanmanServer
```

You will, of course, need to be running as Admin to make such changes.

Comment: So if I write this to lines of code in CMD I will be able to return all the services to their default mode at once?

Comment: Yes. Find the names (as opposed to the "Display Names") of all the services that you want to edit - you can see the name by double-clicking on a service in services.msc, it's called "Service name" at the top of the properties box - and build a script (.CMD or .BAT file) that basically repeats the two lines in the answer with the names of each service you want to control substituted in. Note that the space after the `=` sign is intentional. Remember that you'll need to run the script as Admin.

Comment: alright thanks I will definately check it out, but one last questoin, Where should I write the names of the services, in the beginning ?

Comment: The `LanmanServer` part in the example is a service name. You would need to replace it with the name of the service you wanted to modify, for each such service. You could, if you want to, build a script (or short C program, if you feel like calling the Service Control Manager APIs yourself) that pulls service names from a list/array, to save the effort of copy-pasting those two lines and changing the name each time, but it probably wouldn't come out ahead on effort.

Comment: Please mark my answer as "Accepted" if this is what you were looking for. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, though I did it already